# how do I disable the cache on for a single image (a single page)?

Tags: c#, asp.net

**ASP.NET Image Caching Problem (How to Disable it?)**.IE browser load old image from directory C:\Documents and Settings...\Local Settings\Temporary Internet Files

```
   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MembershipUser user = Membership.GetUser();
      imCropped.ImageUrl = (File.Exists(Server.MapPath("..") + @"\Users\" + user.ProviderUserKey.ToString() + @"\" + user.ProviderUserKey.ToString() + ".gif"))? "~/Users/" + user.ProviderUserKey.ToString() + "/" + user.ProviderUserKey.ToString() + ".gif" : "~/Images/thumb.gif";
}

protected void ButtonJcrop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

       ...

        String mapPath = @"\Users\" + user.ProviderUserKey.ToString() + @"\" + user.ProviderUserKey.ToString() + ".gif";
        bmpCropped.Save(Server.MapPath("..") + mapPath);
        imCropped.ImageUrl = Request.ApplicationPath + mapPath;
        ...
}
```

Comment: Please rephrase the question.

Comment: sentence make easier understand user question thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can add to the img url aquery string param with just a random numbers :

```
<img src="http://www.walaa.co.il/t.jpg?c=2342342"/>
```

it can be like `Datetime.Ticks` or something else.

```
ImageUrl = (File.Exists(string.Format("{0}\\Users\\{1}\\{1}.gif?c={2}", Server.MapPath(".."), user.ProviderUserKey.ToString(), DateTime.Now.Ticks))) ? string.Format("~/Users/{0}/{0}.gif?c={1}" , user.ProviderUserKey.ToString(), DateTime.Now.Ticks) : "~/Images/thumb.gif";
```

Comment: This works but is not an optimum solution. If your image may benefit from caching you can create the number by hashing the file.

Comment: @linkerro I dont think that hashing the IMG will give better performance. BTW - I can add it also in JS  - and not in SERVER side. but I prefer doing it while generating the IMG and just send datetime.ticks.

Comment: @PMD the name is constant. the QueryString param can be anything.

Comment: image crop server side then show thumb but image cached.not Dynamically Change The ImageUrl Of Image

Comment: @PMD I dont see the problem. if you want to invalidate cache - this is the solution. Cant you add a querystring after the filename ? and why didnt you write this in the question ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir it does have an impact on the server due to the hashing function but it performs better on the client. It does depend on what you want though.

Comment: @linkerro If you proof me that hashing a picture and adding its hash to the QueryString is BETTER PERFORMANCE than just use ticks - I'll erase my answer.

Comment: I agree with @linkerro here; this solution, while simple and easy, actually causes *over-caching* of images that will never be used again. Dozens - or hundreds - of copies of the same image will litter the cache.

Comment: @AndrewBarber isnt the OP wanted to remove cache for pictures ?

Comment: @Royi which this solution actually does *not* do; it causes over-caching instead. The proper answer is to modify the appropriate HTTP headers to prevent caching.

Comment: @AndrewBarber modifying HTTP headers is also a solution.